# ajax - Prevent double click on submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, double-submit-prevention

**How can I prevent the user from double clicking submit button on my signup form which is an ajax partial view?**

I regret to ask since this would have already been asked. I just can't find a clear working answer now matter where I search. Disabling the button prevent submit. Using a var javascript clickcount+alert+return_false does not reset.

Environment: asp.net mvc3

**View:**
Form displays onload: `@RenderPage("_SignupForm.cshtml")`

**Submission using:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Signup", null,
     new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = "signupForm", 
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    LoadingElementId="progress"
                }
     ))
```

Submit control: `<input type="submit" value="Sign up" />`

**SignupController :**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SignupModel formvalues)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    string errors = "";
    if (TryValidateModel(formvalues))
    {
        errors = SignupAPI.Signup(formvalues); //includes custom validation
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid == false || string.IsNullOrEmpty(errors) == false)
    {
        ViewBag.Errors = errors;
        return PartialView("_SignupForm", formvalues);
    }
    else
        return Redirect(string.Concat("http://localhost/welcome"));
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try with the following script:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $(':submit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Make sure you execute it also in the success callback of your AJAX request in order to reattach the `submit` event when the form is replaced with a new content in the DOM, or the second time it might no longer work.

Comment: This works great except if you're listening to `$("form").on("invalid-form.validate"` to capture invalid form submissions, the call to `.valid()` will cause the listener to fire twice.

Comment: This works great except if you're listening to `$("form").on("invalid-form.validate"` to capture invalid form submissions, the [call to `.valid()` will cause the listener to fire twice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28683504/1366033).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: submission was not working because onclick was not returning true**

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up" onclick="this.disabled = true; return true;"/>
```

this will disable the button and the second click on the button won't work

Comment: @Arturo: The form fails to submit at all now.

Comment: @Arturo: The form submits, however, for some odd reason, the returned page is only the view and not the surrounding layout. I suspect the ajax call is being circumvented. I have a Thread.Sleep(5000) and I do not see the ajax indicator while waiting for the postback.

Comment: can you post your form element once is being rendered in your browser?

Comment: @Arturo `<form action="/Signup" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#progress" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#signupForm" id="form0" method="post">`. Before, i had changed the command to `form0.submit()`

Comment: @Arturo: thanks for trying to help. I tried the new disableElement function and the result is that the form does not post.

Comment: try with the second option, just the submit input `<input type="submit" value="Sign Up" onclick="this.disabled = true; return true;"/>` the problem is that the onclick was not returning true

Comment: @Arturo: same result. Button disables and form does not submit.