# How to prevent user second click on form submit with ajax submit and show progress

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, post

I have an sign in form in ASP.NET MVC 3

After clicking submit it is taking a bit time to submit the form because there is a lot of things taking place. as a result user may click the button once again thinking that something wrong and something very bad may happened.

So i just may enable/disable the button it is probably the easiest way to prevent second click, but i would rather change form post to ajax way.

Si what i am thinking to do: After user click submit i want to display popup/div saying that the request being processed and showing some kind of ajax lader there and after form being processed i want user to follow to the Action according with server controller logic(the client side doesn't know where user will be redirected.)

Is it possible to do ? What is you opinion? How can i do it better way?

Currently i am looking in to [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit) may be it would help, but if you may suggest something it would be great.

Also just found this solution [ajax - Prevent double click on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434840/ajax-prevent-double-click-on-submit) but i think i still would like display popup with progress.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, and in the past I have used the `.attr("disabled","disabled")` to disable the button on the first click, then the second click does not get triggered. In the success (or error) method of the JQuery ajax response use `.removeAttr("disabled")`

EDIT:

To add a pop-up you are normally just displaying a `<div>` and hiding it when processing is finished.

So by default you div CSS is

```
#myPopUp{
display: none;
top: 50px;
left: 50px;
width: 250px;
height: 100px;
background-color:darkblue;
background-color:white;     
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="myPopUp">This is a popup</div>`
```

now when you are adding the disabled to the button you can also display the pop-up with `$("#myPopUp").show()` and hide it again just after you do the remove disabled on the button `$("#myPopUp").hide()`

Comment: What about pop up with progress?

Comment: And one more thing i just thought, if there will be any validation errors form server i need to close this popup and display them, is it easy to do?

Comment: Yes you just put the same `.hide()` in the error method. I mentioned that already ;)