# Disable "submit" button after form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, form-submit

I have a form like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "_identity" }))
{
// element here

 <input class="buttonblue" type="submit" value="Save" id="Submit1" />
}
```

It is validate by `Model`.

It's working fine. And now I want to detect if this request is reached at controller action after validate.

Actually I want to disable `submit button` when request is reached at controller.

I have tried following. But I think this is not correct.

```
 $('#_identity').submit(function () {
     $("#Submit1").val("Saving...");
     $("#Submit1").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 });
```

This is called before request reached at controller and before validate.

I want simple thing if form is validated and request reached at controller then user can't hit submit button again.

Comment: What would be the point? - you are submitting the form to the controller so even though you disable the button, you have left the page (unless you submit using ajax) and you would be rendering a new page.

Comment: I want simple thing if form is validated and request is reached to controller then user can't click again. @StephenMuecke

Comment: If you submit the form and its validated on the server, then redirect somewhere else (e.g. to a details page). What would be the point of returning to the same view when it cant even be edited! And if you did want to do this, then assign a `ViewBag` property indicating success, then use javascript to read it and disable the button (but it would make no sense at all to do this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this.

Using

```
  $('#_identity').submit(function () {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $(':submit', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $(':submit', this).val('Saving...');
            }
        });
```

I have found it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434840/ajax-prevent-double-click-on-submit)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ajax.BeginForm` this way:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", "controller", new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod ="Post",OnBegin ="OnBegin",OnSuccess="OnSuccess",OnFailure="OnFailure"},new { id = "_identity" }))
{
// element here

 <input class="buttonblue" type="submit" value="Save" id="Submit1" />
}
```

and js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function OnBegin() {

        // disable submit button here
    }

    function OnSuccess() {

        // enable submit button here
    }

    function OnFailure() {

        // enable submit button in case of failure
    }

</script>
```

Comment: These functions aren't calling

Comment: check jquery-unbotrusive is included or not