# ASP.Net Core client-side validation: is there a "validation succeeded" DOM event?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have an ASP.Net Core Razor page that uses Bootstrap and does client-side validation.

The form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
...
```

_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml looks like this:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    ...
```

Everything works fine.  If the user fails to enter a required field or enters a number that exceeds the maximum, the form won't submit and the offending field is highlighted in red.

Is there a DOM event triggered on "validation succeeded"?

I would like to execute some JavaScript after I know the form is "OK", but before it's actually POSTED to the server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683504/check-if-form-is-valid-without-re-running-jquery-validation

Answer (score 1):

If you want a **quick turn-key solution**, you can simply include the `jQuery Validation Plugin`. The *valid* condition returns true only if its valid.

> Answer: you can then `rxJs-subscribe` to it by sending the `data structure` or the `control` in to get the event out using this [jquery.observable](https://github.com/erosb/jquery.observable) plugin

Below is how the Jquery Valid works:

Form:

---

```
$("form").valid(); 
// or
if($("form").valid()) {
 //VALID continue
}
```

---

Control:

```
$("[name='CountyOfBirth']").valid(); // RETURNS true/false
```

---

On Submit: you can also get similar results of the valid event by checking on form submit

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    if($(this).valid()) {
       //VALID
    } else {
       //ERROR
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use j[Query Unobtrusive Ajax](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive) with the form in the razor view.

First, you will need to include jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax script:

```
npm i jquery-ajax-unobtrusive -D  (or --save-dev)
```

Secondly, you need to enable unobtrusive ajax on your form by adding specific custom `data-` attributes:

```
<form method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate
  data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post"
  data-ajax-begin="onFormBegin"
  data-ajax-complete="onFormComplete">
```

There are [other attributes](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax) you can use.

Here you can register callbacks, for example, on the beginning and the completion of form submit:

```js
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            window.onFormBegin = function() {
                // This is the place where you can execute some Javascript 
                // after you know the form is "OK", but before it's actually 
                // POSTED to the server.
            };

            window.onFormComplete = function(request, status) {
                // ...
            };
        });
    </script>
}
```